# m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle - why does my code work in production but not in dev environment?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, iis-express

After I enabled HTTPS in my project, I started to receive an error page with this error: `m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle`

The code runs great in production on the web server.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0.

I have updated sslFlags to `<access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />`
and I have ensured iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication is set
to `<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>`

The below are my IIS Express application pool settings:

```
<applicationPools>
            <add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr4ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="UnmanagedClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Classic" autoStart="true" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeLoader="v4.0">
                <processModel loadUserProfile="true" />                                
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
```

full text from error page:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.

Source Error:


Line 383:                    HttpClientCertificate httpCert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
Line 384:                    X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(httpCert.Certificate);
Line 385:                    _subject = x509Cert.Subject;
Line 386:                    _sCustomerId = CustomerQueries.getCustomerId(_subject);
Line 387:                    LoadCustomerAttributes(CustomerQueries.getCustomerAttributes(_sCustomerId));

Source File: C:\$TFS\Reports\Projects\WebMaster\Customers\Classes\Customer.cs    Line: 385

Stack Trace:


[CryptographicException: m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.]
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.ThrowIfContextInvalid() +12505161
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.get_Subject() +14
   ReportsRG.Projects.WebMaster.Customers.Classes.Customer.GetUserDataFromCertificate() in C:\$TFS\SMRT\Dev\ReportsRG\Projects\WebMaster\Customers\Classes\Customer.cs:385
   ReportsRG.Projects.WebMaster.Customers.Classes.Customer..ctor() in C:\$TFS\SMRT\Dev\ReportsRG\Projects\WebMaster\Customers\Classes\Customer.cs:322
   MVCPages.Controllers.SmrtController.Index() in C:\$TFS\SMRT\Dev\MVCPages\Controllers\SmrtController.cs:39
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9850009
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0() +26
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +107
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +23
   Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) +64
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +56
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +91
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +23
   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) in /_/WEB/Src/Web/Web/ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.cs:164
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +56
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +91
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +9956298
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: "m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle", where did you see that? As part of an error page or an error dialog? Show a full screen shot or there isn't enough information for others to help.

Comment: @LexLi I added the full text from the error page to the question. I get the error page first thing when I run the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was updating the wrong `ApplicationHost.config` file.

The correct one is located at `.vs\config` in the solution root.

I was updating the one located at: `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\IISExpress\config\`

Once I updated the correct `ApplicationHost.config` file, the code started working in my local development environment.

Answer (score 1):

The call stack at least gives enough hints on what to look for next.

```
Line 383:                    HttpClientCertificate httpCert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
Line 384:                    X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(httpCert.Certificate);
Line 385:                    _subject = x509Cert.Subject;
```

This piece of code tries to grab the client certificate sent by the browser, and then access its `Subject` property. This access attempt failed and an exception happened,

```
[CryptographicException: m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.]
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.ThrowIfContextInvalid() +12505161
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.get_Subject() +14
```

Since .NET Framework in general wraps up native Windows API, so the exception itself can be quite confusing.

"The code runs great in production on the web server", so that I can assume your server administrators have configured this production machine to know how to build full chains for client certificates (very common server configuration), but you might not have done the same on your development machine. Talk to the server administrators and learn what you missed.

In the meantime, you might set a break at line 384 and analyze more details of `httpCert`. That might help you find out what settings are missing.

Comment: I followed your debug advice and found that the certificate is showing as empty. For some reason ,in the local Visual Studio environment, the certificate is not being passed to the application via HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate like it does in the production environment does.

Comment: @TysonGibby You need to change IIS/IIS Express setting to require client certificates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis#configure-ssl-settings-2 Since you are using IIS Express with VS, you have to manually edit `applicationHost.config` or use a tool like my Jexus Manager.

Comment: My understanding is that this is accomplished by the following two settings which I already have set in my Applicationhost.config file: `<access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />` and `<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>` Is there anything else I need to add or update?

Comment: @TysonGibby not `SslNegotiateCert` but `SslRequireCert` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access#attributes

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am required to use `SslNegotiateCert`, it does work for what is required in our environment.